# Accessing ActiveRecord Object with Joins and Includes through options_from_collection_for_select()

Tags: ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, html-select

When I use:

```
<%= @employees.first.actor.name %>
# someones name...
```

Works! But when I do:

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@employees, 'id', 'actor.name')
```

for a select tag on the same page with the same method in the controller; it goes :

```
undefined method `actor.name' for #<Employee:0x0000000b0f3218>
```

isnt 'options_from_collection_for_select()' a shorthand for the former? why am I getting this error?

I used:

```
@employees = Employee.includes(:actor).joins(:actor)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `options_from_collection_for_select` is kind of a short cut, but it works by using `send` to call methods with the given name on the object. And `send` cannot handle nested calls like `actor.name`.

I would solve this by [delegating](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) the method `actor_name` to `actor.name`. Add the following to your model:

```
# app/models/employee.rb
delegate :name, to: :actor, prefix: true
```

Then change your view to:

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@employees, :id, :actor_name)
```